# How do I quickly change the default action of a contact in the favorites widget?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-droid-incredible, app-widgets

I see no obvious way to change the default action of a contact that's added to the Favorites widget. I have to remove that contact from the `Favorites` group, and re-add that contact (which then prompts me for the default action, like `View Contact`, or `Send Mail`). Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3):

Finally tried this, it's quicker to do the following:

1. Select the contact name from the Favorites widget (the icon performs the action, the name shows you their details).
2. Select Menu > More.
3. Select Set widget action.
4. Select call, text, etc.