# How can I edit or remove people from the favourite contacts widget on my HTC Legend?

Tags: contacts, app-widgets

How can I edit or remove people from the favourite contacts widget on my HTC Legend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access them through the group "Starred in Android" in GMail

Comment: The group name is actually "Favorites" on my phone

Comment: @Casebash: The phone calls them "Favorites" but if you pull up contacts in Gmail, the group will be called "Starred in Android" there.

Answer (score 1):

For editing, this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1490/15) should help, although it's specific to the HTC incredible. For removing, it's the same idea (select contact name, not icon) then remove them from the Favorites Group. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To change whether a contact is a favorite or not, go to your contact list, click on the contact name, then toggle the "star" in the top right corner of the contact screen.

Comment: That's what I was going to answer, but does this custom widget on the Legend use that flag or its own algorithm to determine favorites?

Comment: I have the same issue on my HTC Desire - I think adding a person via the widget adds them to a Favourites contact list but I don't see any way of editing this list (I don't seem to have the same contact list ui that you refer to - my People list doesn't have stars in it).

Comment: The People page *does* list the favourited people as belonging to the group "Favourite", but if you edit the contact then "Favourite" isn't one of the listed groups.

Comment: @therefromhere Ah, must be one of those HTC Sense-only kind of thing

Comment: I think this might be a bug to be honest - I'm on 2.1 still, I'll investigate further and report it if it's not fixed in 2.2.

Comment: I don't have a star on the contacts screen

Comment: @Casebash it must be because you are using HTC Sense.  On a stock phone there is a big star in the top right to favorite contacts.

Comment: @therefromhere: It must be a bug in 2.1.  I'm running 2.2 on my Incredible, and "Favorites" is listed in the groups, so to remove them I just un-check the box when editing the contact.

Answer (score 0):

Removing it from "favourites" or "starred in android" didn't work for me. I don't have any star either on my HTC Wildfire.

You have to find your contact in the "Phone" list (this one where you go when you want to call someone, middle bottom of the desktop). Then you touch it, wait until menu arrives and... tap "remove from favourites". Interesting that you won't find this option in "People" app, or in contact details either.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to Contacts > Details and add or remove the star to make them favorite or not. It worked for me.