# Contacts stuck in favourites widget on HTC Legend

Tags: contacts

Until recently, I was able to remove contacts using [this method](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/edit-or-remove-favourite-contacts-on-htc-widget). Now those methods don't work. I can remove a person from the favourites group, but that only removes them from the widget until I restart. When I visit the contact profile I see them listed as being in the favourites group, but when I go to edit, they are not listed as a member. Removing the contact from my "Starred on Android" group doesn't work either. Is there any other way to remove contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to delete the widget, clear the data and cache for Contacts Storage, re-sync, and re-add the widget.  That should get rid of bad data that is likely screwing things up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I actually solved by going to the group, then editing the group's members; rather than going to the person, then editing the person's group

Comment: That's strange.  Oh Google ...